# Plot entropy, avg rewards etc from Stable Baselines

Tags: python, openai-gym

I have built a custom environment by implementing the `step, reset and render` methods from `StableBaselines` but I don't know how to print some plots.

For instance, how many times my agent (in a Discrete action space) took action = 0, 1, 2, etc...

What signal did the environment give.

How the rewards moved?

I found about results_plotter but couldn't find many info of it.

```
results_plotter.plot_results(["."], 10e6, results_plotter.X_TIMESTEPS, "Market rewards")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pre-made tool for this at the moment. Have a look at the [Monitor](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/blob/master/stable_baselines/bench/monitor.py#L13) wrapper and how it tracks the episodic rewards. It will generate a log file which you can use to get some metrics out. This is your best bet imo.

I recommend also taking a look at [Tensorboard](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/tensorboard.html) too, as it might provide some real-time info.